# Using Spark From Within My Application

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am relatively new to Spark. I have created scripts which are run for offline, batch processing tasks but now I am attempting to use it from within a live application (i.e. not using `spark-submit`).

My application looks like the following:

1. An HTTP request will be received to initiate a data-processing tasks. The payload of the request will contain data needed for the spark job (time window to look at, data types to ignore, weights to use for ranking algorithms, etc).
2. Processing begins, which will eventually produce a result. The result is expected to fit into memory.
3. The result is sent to an endpoint (Written to a single file, sent to a client through Web Socket or SSE, etc)

The fact that the job is initiated by an HTTP request, and that the spark-job is dependant on data in this request, seems to imply that I can't use `spark-submit` for this problem. Although this originally seemed fairly straightforward to me, I've run into some issues that no amount of Googling has been able to solve. The main issue is exemplified by the following:

```
object MyApplication {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val config = ConfigFactory.load()

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf(true)
    .setMaster(config.getString("spark.master-uri"))
    .setAppName(config.getString("spark.app-name"))

    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val localData = Seq.fill(10000)(1)
    // The following produces ClassNotFoundException for Test
    val data = sc.parallelize[Int](localData).map(i => new Test(i))
    println(s"My Result ${data.count()}")
    sc.stop()
  }
}

class Test(num: Int) extends Serializable
```

Which is then run

```
sbt run
...
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, 127.0.0.1): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.Test 
...
```

I have classes within my application that I want to create and manipulate while using Spark. I've considered extracting all of these classes into a stand-alone library which I can send using `.setJars("my-library-of-classes")` but that will be very awkward to work with and deploy. I've also considered not using any classes within the spark logic and only using tuples. That would be just as awkward to use.

Is there a way for me to do this? Have I missed something obvious or are we really forced to use `spark-submit` to communicate with Spark?

Comment: 'I can send using .setJars("my-library-of-classes") but that will be very awkward to work with and deploy'. Well, that's actually a common practice from my point of view. There's plenty of questions with exactly this problem (ClassNotFoundException) answered with such solution. The main issue here is that every worker needs to have such classes in the classpath when executing transformations (a `map` in your example). You might find this project interesting: https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Comment: Then maybe my problem is that I do not know how to easily handle the double dependency of this library; my application can easily include the dependency in my build file, but what do I put in `.setJars`? Do I need to deploy this jar to a managed directory and then reference it in my build.sbt and setJars?  Do I need to make two changes every time I upgrade: one to the build file and another to the `setJars` string?

Answer (score 1):

Currently spark-submit is the only way to submit spark jobs to a cluster. So you have to create a fat jar consisting of all your classes and dependencies and use it with spark-submit. You could use command line arguments to pass either data or paths to configuration files

Comment: That's fine for manually using the script, using a cron job, or forking the original process, but how do I then retrieve the results of the Spark job? Do I need to treat Spark jobs as 'fire-and-forget' and have the job itself communicate the results to the endpoint?

Comment: Fire and forget is not too bad. But maybe you should take a look at [Ooyala spark job server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver)